# Embedding font into .mxd using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, font

I use a custom made font for symbols on my map in ArcMap 10. Is there anyway to embed the font in the .mxd file so I don't have to distribute the font files with instructions on how to install it to my users?

On the [ESRI blog](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/03/28/fonts-in-arcgis-symbols/) I found this:

> Sharing ArcGIS documents with character marker symbols
>
> A critical thing to know is that if you want to share your ArcMap, ArcScene, or ArcGlobe document with others, they also need to have the font on their machine in order for the symbol to appear correctly.  If they don’t, the marker symbol will undergo a font substitution and will be replaced with a character from a different font. Don’t forget that you may need to check the permission on the font you want to share.

But that was from 2012, so perhaps the feature has been added since then?

Please note that I am not looking for instructions on how to embed the font into an exported .pdf - I want to keep it in the .mxd file.

Comment: This would be handy. I'd wager that cartographic representations embedded in the geometry/ style files are one possible solution.  Maybe you could supply the users a python script that copies the font to the correct location instead?

Comment: Using python to install the font is a good idea, but it still hinges on having an extra file present. Could you develop on "cartographic representations embedded in the geometry/style files", I'm not sure I follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge **No**.

You can embed the fonts to an exported map
if the build-in security flag of the font file allows it.

Comment: Sad, but probably true.